# Hystrix not interrupting the long running thread

Tags: thread-safety, threadpoolexecutor, fallback, hystrix

I am new to hystrix and have created below POC where it randomly selects from execution from below use-case.

1. zero Error code (Successful)
2. Non-zero error code
3. Runtime Exception
4. Infinite loop

When it chooses the 4th one, it does not interrupt the thread. If I put the Thread.sleep() for longer time then it interrupts but doesn't interrupt the infinite loop.

Can someone tell me whether I am doing any mistake in wraping the task in the HystrixCommand? How do I interrupt the long/infinitely running threads using hystrix?

```
public class HystrixTesting extends HystrixCommand<HystrixResult> {

    private String institutionId;
    private boolean isTimedOut = true;
    private boolean isRunExecuted = false;
    private HystrixResult hystrixResult = new HystrixResult();

    private HystrixErrorMap map = HystrixErrorMap.getInstance();
    String executionType;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HystrixTesting.class);

    public HystrixTesting(String institutionId, HystrixResult hystrixResult) {
        super(Setter.withGroupKey(
                HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("HystrixTest"))
                .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(institutionId)));
        this.hystrixResult = hystrixResult;
        this.institutionId = institutionId;
    }

    @Override
    protected HystrixResult run() throws WIFrameworkException {

        isRunExecuted = true;
        logger.info("Hystrix:: Execution started for InstitutionId="
                + institutionId);
        HystrixTask hystrixTask = new HystrixTask();
        try {
            hystrixResult = hystrixTask.executeTask(institutionId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isTimedOut = false;
        }
        logger.info("Hystrix:: Execution finished for InstitutionId="
                + institutionId);

        int errorCode = hystrixResult.getScriptExecutionStatusCode();
        String errorMessage = hystrixResult.getScriptExecutionStatusMessage();
        if (HystrixErrorMap.isInErrorCodeList(errorCode)) {
            map.add(institutionId, new ContextInfo(errorCode, errorMessage));
            isTimedOut = false;
            logger.info("Hystrix:: Throwing runtime exception in hystrix command due to ErrorCode="
                    + errorCode + ", InstitutionId=" + institutionId);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        if (map.get(institutionId) != null)
            map.remove(institutionId);
        isTimedOut = false;
        return hystrixResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected HystrixResult getFallback() {
        logger.info("Hystrix:: Fallback method called, threw an Exception in run() or hystrix has already blocked the execution for InstitutionId="
                + institutionId);

        if (isTimedOut && isRunExecuted) {
            String errMsg = "Hystrix:: Hystrix Command Timeout Occured while executing request for InstitutionId="
                    + institutionId;
            logger.error(errMsg + ", InstitutionId=" + institutionId);

            hystrixResult.setScriptExecutionStatus(102, errMsg);
            map.add(institutionId, new ContextInfo(102, errMsg));
        } else if (!isRunExecuted) {
            ContextInfo staleContext = map.get(institutionId);

            logger.error("Hystrix:: Hystrix blocked the execution for InstitutionId="
                    + institutionId
                    + " due to ErrorCode="
                    + staleContext.getErrorCode()
                    + ", ErrorMessage="
                    + staleContext.getErrorMessage());

            hystrixResult.setScriptExecutionStatus(staleContext.getErrorCode(),
                    "Circuit is broken for " + institutionId + " due to "
                            + staleContext.getErrorMessage());
        }
        return hystrixResult;
    }

}

**HystrixTask.java**

public class HystrixTask {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HystrixTask.class);

    static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static int zeroErrorCounter = 1;
    public static int nonZeroErrorCounter = 1;
    public static int runTimeErrorCounter = 1;
    public static int timeOutErrorCounter = 1;

    static {
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
    }

    /**
     * Provides the output randomly 1. Successful(0 Error code) 2. Non zero
     * error code 3. Runtime Exception 4. Timeout
     * 
     * @param institutionId
     * @param scriptctx
     * @param executionType
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public HystrixResult executeTask(String institutionId) {
        logger.info("inside executeTask() Hystrix.getCurrentThreadExecutingCommand().name():"
                + Hystrix.getCurrentThreadExecutingCommand().name());

        HystrixResult result = new HystrixResult();
        try {
            int random = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
            switch (random) {
            case 1:
                result.setScriptExecutionStatus(0, "Successfully executed");
                logger.info("Hystrix:: Zero Error request served:"
                        + zeroErrorCounter++);
                return result;
            case 2:
                result.setScriptExecutionStatus(101, "Layout changed");
                logger.info("Hystrix:: Non Zero Error request served:"
                        + nonZeroErrorCounter++);
                return result;
            case 3:
                logger.info("Hystrix:: Run time Error request served:"
                        + runTimeErrorCounter++);
                int error = 10 / 0;
            case 4:
                result.setScriptExecutionStatus(1000, "Timeout exception");
                logger.info("Hystrix:: Timeout Error request started for:"
                        + timeOutErrorCounter++);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(101000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                logger.info("Hystrix:: Timeout Error request served:"
                        + timeOutErrorCounter);
                return result;
            default:
                logger.info("Hystrix:: default:");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("inside exception Hystrix.getCurrentThreadExecutingCommand().name():"
                    + Hystrix.getCurrentThreadExecutingCommand().name());
            result.setScriptExecutionStatus(1001, "Run time exception");
            logger.info("Hystrix:: Cautht: " + runTimeErrorCounter);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```